# Sklearn and gensim's TF-IDF implementation

Tags: scikit-learn, tf-idf, gensim

I've been trying to determine the similarity between a set of documents, and one of the methods I'm using is the cosine similarity with the results of the TF-IDF.

I tried to use both sklearn and gensim's implementations, which give me similar results, but my own implementation results in a different matrix.

After analyzing, I noticed that the their implementations are different from the ones I've studied and came across:

Sklearn and gensim use raw counts as the TF, and apply L2 norm
on the resulting vectors.

On the other side, the implementations I found will normalize the term count,
like

```
TF = term count / sum of all term counts in the document
```

My question is, what is the difference with their implementations? Do they give better results in the end, for clustering or other purposes?

EDIT(So the question is clearer):
What is the difference between normalizing the end result vs normalizing the term count at the beggining?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up understanding why the normalization is done at the end of the tf-idf calculations instead of doing it on the term frequencies.

After searching around, I noticed they use L2 normalization in order to facilitate cosine similarity calculations.

So, instead of using the formula `dot(vector1, vector2) / (norm(vector1) * norm(vector2))` to get the similarity between 2 vectors, we can use directly the result from the `fit_transform` function: `tfidf * tfidf.T`, without the need to normalize, since the norm for the vectors is already 1.

I tried to add normalization on the term frequency, but it just gives out the same results in the end, when normalizing the whole vectors, ending up being a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

With scikit-learn, you can set the normalization as desired when calling `TfidfTransformer()` by setting `norm` to either `l1`, `l2`, or `none`.

If you try this with `none`, you may get similar results to your own hand-rolled tf-idf implementation.

The normalization is typically used to reduce the effects of document length on a particular tf-idf weighting so that words appearing in short documents are treated on more equal footing to words appearing in much longer documents.

Comment: Yeah, I already got similar results by hand when I checked their implementation.

I think I wasn't explicit with my question, I was asking what is the difference between normalizing the end result vs normalizing the term frequency at the beggining, since both methods will be used to counter the document length.